# Excel 2016 - VBA error ref table

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

Hope someone can help I'm getting an error on the part of the code below with >>>>> next to it?

This occurs when I'm referencing a sheet by its code name and not its tab name.

Any help or advice??

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
    lngStart = Sheet5.Range("A2").Value 'assume this is the start date
    lngEnd = Sheet5.Range("A3").Value 'assume this is the end date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet100.Visible = True
    Sheet105.Visible = True

    'assume you have field name / label in D29
    Sheet100.Unprotect Password:="MM@MM.com"
    Sheet100.Select
   >>>>>>>>> ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_summary_1").Range.AutoFilter field:=8,
   >>>>>     Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
   >>>>>     Operator:=xlAnd, _
   >>>>>     Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd
    Sheet100.Protect Password:="MM@MM.com", AllowFiltering:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

    Sheet105.Unprotect Password:="MM@MM.com"
    Sheet105.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_kpi").Range.AutoFilter field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd
    Sheet105.Protect Password:="MM@MM.com", AllowFiltering:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

    Sheet3.Select

    Sheet100.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheet105.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Sheets(Range("H19").Value).Select
Exit Sub
```

Thank you in advance
J

Comment: Missing a line continuation (_) after `field:=8,`, or is your code not wrapped like that in the VB editor ?  What exactly is the error you're getting ?

Comment: Why use `Sheet100.Select` and immediately make a call on `ActiveSheet.ListObjects()`?  What's wrong with skipping the selection and using `Sheet100.ListObjects()`?

Comment: Thank you Tim & Comintern. Tim you you resolved the issue with the  (_) and Comintern I amended the VBA as you send and learnt something further in this process. Thank you again both and have a good day. J